# Tweepy: Auto Tweet Images From Folder?

Tags: python, tweepy

New here, First post aswell.

I'm currently trying to use Tweepy. I've successfully set it up so far and I'm able to tweet single images. So the code runs fine.

The purpose of this is because I run an account that tweets images only, no actual text tweets.

I've a folder of 100's of images I go through everyday to tweet and found out about tweepy, Is it possible to be able to tell Tweepy to go into the folder of the images and select 1 or any 1 at random? I've did extensive searching and couldn't find anything at all.

All help is greatly, greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I've got at the moment (python-2).

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep

consumer_key = 'Removed'
consumer_secret = 'Removed'
access_token = 'Removed'
access_token_secret = 'Removed'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_with_media('Image')
sleep(900)

print 'Tweeted!'
```

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're iterating 100 times, given that you have 100 photos in your dir. I hope you don't mind, I took the liberty of placing your twitter api instantiation/auth in a function (for reusability's sake :) ). For the `getPathsFromDir()` function, I adapted GoToLoop's solution from [processing.org](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/24768/python-load-random-images-from-a-folder-without-knowing-the-file-name). You might want to check out the link reference/link for more details. Also, practice placing your `api.update[_with_media,_status]()` in `try` - `except` blocks. You'll never know an odd exception would be raised by the api. I hope my implementation works for you!

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep

folderpath = "/path/to/your/directory/"
def tweepy_creds():
    consumer_key = 'Removed'
    consumer_secret = 'Removed'
    access_token = 'Removed'
    access_token_secret = 'Removed'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    return tweepy.API(auth)

def getPathsFromDir(dir, EXTS="extensions=,png,jpg,jpeg,gif,tif,tiff,tga,bmp"):
    return this.listPaths(folder, EXTS)

def tweet_photos(api):
    imagePaths = getPathsFromDir(this.dataPath(folderpath))
    for x in imagePaths:
        status = "tweet text here"
        try:
            api.update_with_media(filename=x,status=status)
            print "Tweeted!"
            sleep(900)
        except Exception as e:
            print "encountered error! error deets: %s"%str(e)
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tweet_photos(tweepy_creds())
```

/ogs

Comment: AttributeError: module 'this' has no attribute 'dataPath'